# How to prevent twig to render embedded form automatically?

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, embedding

I whant to iplement embedded form. So exists customer which has company. In single form during registration he must describe youself and his company. Therefore I have:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Company;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CompanyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'type',
                'choice',
                [
                    'choices' => Company::choices()
                ]
            )
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('licenseNumber', 'text')
            ->add('country', 'country')
            ->add('officeAddress', 'text')
            ->add('registrationAddress', 'text')
            ->add('phone', 'text')
            ->add('fax', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('description', 'textarea')
            ->add('Documents', 'text', [ 'compound' => true ])
        ;

        $builder->setMethod('POST');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Company'
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_company';
    }
}




namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class RegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add(
                'password',
                'repeated',
                [
                    'first_options'  => [
                        'label' => 'Password'
                    ],
                    'second_options' => [
                        'label' => 'Repeat Password'
                    ],
                    'type'           => 'password',
                    'property_path'  => 'rawPassword',
                ]
            )
            ->add('Companies', 'collection', ['type' => new CompanyType()] )
            ->add('submit', 'submit')
            ->setMethod('POST')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults(
                [
                    'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Customer'
                ]
            )
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_register';
    }
}
```

So in RegistreType I want embed CompanyType. Therefore in my registration controller I do:

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($customer = $this->getUser()) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('_profile_index');
        }

        $customerManager = $this->get('app.services.customer_manager');

        $customer = new Customer();
        $company = new Company();
        $customer->getCompanies()->add($company);

        $form = $this->createForm(new RegisterType(), $customer);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $customerManager->create($form->getData());

            //return $this->redirectToRoute('_security_register_confirmation');
        }

        return $this->render(
            'AppBundle:Security:register.html.twig',
            [
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ]
        );
    }
```

In result  I recive embedded company form but it is rendering  automaticly and as you see it is not good. Pleasy help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have understood! That is because I don't  handle form fields manually e.g.:

```
 {{ form_label(form.Companies[0].name) }}                                   
 {{ form_errors(form.Companies[0].name) }}
 {{ form_widget(form.Companies[0].name) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you know about [Form themes in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes), but I think this might be what you are looking for.

You  have to create a form theme in src\YourBundle\Resources\views\Form (or anywhere else, but this is the path indicated by Symfony's documentation). Let's call it registrationForm.html.twig.

Inside, you will create a custom theme for your personnal use, designing the company form as you desire, this way:

```
{% block _app_company_row %} // or {% block _app_company_widget %}
    // your custom template here
    // see documentation to learn how to do this correctly
    // as this can be rather difficult to understand
{% endblock %}
```

Then you will have to 'call' this theme in your template:

```
{% form_theme form 'YourBundle:Form:registrationForm.html.twig' %}
```

*form* being the twig variable containing your formView instance.

But I thinkthere might be some ohter issues in your question, like 'what is a choice form component?'..

Some infos about the Company entity could help too..